# How OS kernel is exclusively privileged to do some low level stuff?

Tags: kernel

To my understanding, the OS kernel is privileged to perform some low level operations which no other program can, like some low level interrupts or handling multiple cores.

Are there some kind of special instructions which enable this?

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific programming questions, not general operating system design questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer.

The main privilege separation has to do with address space: when run in "supervisor mode", a CPU has access to all of the address space. An OS kernel runs in this mode. A user process does not.

This is why, for instance, a user process on a 32bit Linux host has only a 3 GB address space at its disposal whereas the theoretically available address space is 2^32 = 4 GB: the "stranded" gigabyte is only accessible by the kernel, and the kernel maps its data structures into this gigabyte. A user process attempting to access that address space would see a SIGBUS. This frontier also exists on 64bit machines but is very remote.

In supervisor mode, a running code (kernel) also has the availability to modify the layout of the address space: it means, for instance, that it can render the PCI address space of your video card, or the DMA address space of your device, serial port etc completely invisible to other running codes (processes) in non supervising mode.

The kernel can grant access to low-level operations (such as a disk write) via system calls. When a system call is triggered, the kernel executes the system call on behalf of the process that invoked it, in supervisor mode. When the system call is done or interrupted, the process resumes executions, with its own privileges.

One central part of all this logic in today's processors is the MMU (memory management unit), since this is the component allowing for address space rewrite -- and which is why you could have 32bit machines with more than 4 GB RAM, an impossible thing if a MMU weren't available.

Answer (score 0):

Because OS sets itself up as highest privilege owner while booting and h/w initialization. OS does this with the help of MMU hardware. For example in x86 based processor there are two mechanisms which h/w provides for protection

1. **Segmentation**:

   Segmentation makes your memory look like segments, and to those segments you can assign privilege level (PL) from 0 to 3 , 0 being highest privilege. While booting & initializing  h/w you can assign kernel code segment 0 PL , and once it starts executing user process kernel assigns it PL 3 . If user code try to jump to more privileged kernel code h/w will generate General Protection(GP) Fault (interrupt #13) , which will execute kernel code and it can then choose to kill user process. Similarly, there are instructions like `lidt`, `lgdt` etc. which can only be executed in 0 PL ,  if user  code try to execute them it will generate GP Fault.  Segmentation also solves following problem:

   1. How to represent memory region which contains only executable code?
   2. How to represent  memory region which contains only data ?
2. **Paging**:

   Paging divides memory into pages of size( 4KB/2MB/4MB/1GB) , paging support from  h/w solves following problems :

   1. What if you want to say a page to belong to user or kernel ?
   2. What if you want to say page to be read-only or write-only or both read-write ?

   If user code try to violate any paging rule setup by OS, h/w generates page fault, which executes kernel code ( because OS sets that up during initialization of interrupt/faults/exceptions handlers) , And this way kernel can decide what to do with user process.

Both Segmentation and Paging are more involved topics, but this answer in only within the context of your question.

Answer (score -2):

theoretically : yes, with loads of injections and even hacking you will be able to use even low-level instructionsets but in reality this wont be possible as there are way too many resources which lock certain areas at some time.

With standard languages and standard libraries, you will most likely not gain access to 100% of your hardware becaue thats the way these are designed - taking away crucial and possibly dangerous decisions is what makes complex (and powerful) frameworks even possible. With OSS-operating systems you *may* be able to gain full control but in the end you will be left with the same problems : intersections of kernel-operations with your own operations and without modifying the kernel heavily you'll be unable to gain full control at all times.

If you want 100.0% control over your hardware you'll be forced to write your own bootloader, kernel and operating system - via hardware instructions at Opcode-level you can manipulate virtually everything; using **any** programming language (even ASM) will put limits on you.